# I need to understand the top function, more specific then i already know. The bottom function is pretty much self-explanatory

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions

`bool isOnPerimeter` - function that I need help with.

```
bool isOnPerimeter(int row, int column, int radius)
{
   double dRow=static_cast<double>(row);
   double dColumn=static_cast<double>(column);
   double dRadius=static_cast<double>(radius);

   if (pow(dRow,2.0)+pow(dColumn,2.0)<=pow(dRadius,2.0) &&
          pow(dRow,2.0)+pow(abs(dColumn)+1,2.0) > pow(dRadius,2.0))
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}

void drawCircle(int radius) 
{
   for (int row = -radius;row <= radius;++row) 
   {
      for (int column = -radius;column <= radius;++column)
      {
         if (isOnPerimeter(row,column,radius))
            cout << "*";
         else
            cout << " ";
         cout << endl;
      }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function looks like it's drawing a circle inside the square define by coordinates (-radius,-radius), (radius,radius).

How it does that: consider the trigonometric circle, you know that `sin^2 + cos^2 = R^2`. Since sin and cos are the projections of R on oy and ox axes, all the points inside the circle have the property that `sin^2 + cos^2 < R^2`   and all the points outside the circle have the property `sin^2 + cos^2 > R^2`

In your example you row, col are the equivalent of sin, cos. So you determine the edge of the circle as being all the points for which

```
sin^2 + cos^2 <= R^2   && sin^2 + (cos+1)^2 > R^2
```

Hope this helps